# Azure Data Factory - how to copy specific documents but exclude others in azure storage to another storage

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm a newbie to Azure Data Factory.  I have a list of files below that need copies from Azure storage(A) to storage(B).

1. Create a source dataset and a destination dataset.
2. Create a link service point to the source and a link service point to the destination.

But how can I filter to get specific XML files and exclude others to transfer to storage(B)?

```
 AD01.xml
 AD02.xml
 AD14.xml
 ADA1012.xml
 ADA3120.xml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can I filter to get specific XML files and exclude others to transfer to storage(B)?

It depends on the kind of criteria on which you want to copy.

After creating linked services, create [`datasets`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-datasets-linked-services?tabs=data-factory#create-a-dataset-with-ui) for both source and sink using the linked services.

Currently, `XML` dataset **is not supported as sink in copy activity**, so use **Binary** datasets for both source and sink datasets of the copy activity.

[image]

Similarly create the target dataset and give the path till your target folder.

If you have XML files like below, and **you want copy only files where file name starts with `AD`**, then use wild card file path in copy activity source.

```
AD01.xml
AD02.xml
AD14.xml
ADA1012.xml
ADA3120.xml
first.xml
second.xml
```

[image]

Files will be copied like below.

[image]

**If you want to copy only latest files which were uploaded** in the last 24 hours, use the `StartTime` in UTC like `@adddays(utcnow(),-1)` in the **LastModified** of the copy activity source.

[image]

**If you have a requirement of filtering the filenames based on a manual condition like filename in a particular date format (`file_2024_05_03.xml`)**, then first get all file names list from Get meta data activity.

[image]

Then, pass this list to a Filter activity and check each file name in the filter condition. The file name which gives `true` for the condition expression will be filtered.

Here, for sample I am checking the below condition.

[image]

Then, pass the filtered file names list to For-Each activity. Inside for-loop, use copy activity with source and sink binary dataset and use dataset parameters for the dynamic filenames.

In these ways, you can filter the required files and can copy to target storage account.